# RGB processing with PIL - How to take a single image and produce images with different values RGB?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I want to take an image, then turn it into 9 different images that I add to a list.
I want to take this single image, then change the R value by a large value, then the R value by a half, and finally change R by a smaller value.

I'm struggling to get this to work though.
My logic loop doesn't seem to work, and my images and not being modified.
Any help appreciated.

```
from PIL import Image

# Set the file and open it
file = "Final/charlie.png"
#pic = Image.open(file)

#Convert to RGB, so we dont have to deal with the alpha channel
#pic = pic.convert('RGB')
images = []
count = 0


#Image processing for lage change
def image_processing0(a):
    c = int(a / 10)
    return c

#Create PixelMap
count = 0
while count <3:
    pic = Image.open(file)
    pic = pic.convert('RGB')
    for x in range(pic.size[0]):
            for y in range(pic.size[1]):
                r,g,b = pic.getpixel((x,y))

#Check the count and use logic to appy the processing to the corect channel               
                if count == 1:
                    image_processing0(r)
                    pic.putpixel((x,y),(r,g,b))
                elif count == 2:
                    image_processing0(g)
                    pic.putpixel((x,y),(r,g,b))
                else:
                    image_processing0(b)
                    pic.putpixel((x,y),(r,g,b))
                    
    images.append(pic)  
    count+=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to assign the return of `image_processing0` to `r, g, b`.

Change this:

```
if count == 1:
    image_processing0(r)
    pic.putpixel((x,y),(r,g,b))
elif count == 2:
    image_processing0(g)
    pic.putpixel((x,y),(r,g,b))
else:
    image_processing0(b)
    pic.putpixel((x,y),(r,g,b))
```

To:

```
if count == 1:
    r = image_processing0(r)
    pic.putpixel((x,y),(r,g,b))
elif count == 2:
    g = image_processing0(g)
    pic.putpixel((x,y),(r,g,b))
else:
    b = image_processing0(b)
    pic.putpixel((x,y),(r,g,b))
```

Comment: Perfect thanks Douglas, I cant believe I missed this. You saved me pulling my hair out :-)

Comment: Happy to help :)